# Hosting Jenkins on an Amazon Windows Server virtual machine

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, windows-server-2008-r2

The company I work for has Windows Server 2008 R2 virtual machine on which we want to host Jenkins.

I have installed Jenkins and it resides in the default location (C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins).

Running the Windows service works fine; you can access Jenkins while on the server by browsing the `http://localhost:8080`.

Does anyone know the best way to make this accessible on the internet in general.

Note: We don't have a network of Amazon servers, each server is in its own domain, which is separate from our office domain.

Comment: Unless tcp port 8080 is blocked by your Security Group (which you would have specified while creating your instance), your service should be available on the internet via http://ec2_instance_public_ip:8080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your security group to allow `0.0.0.0/0` to `port 8080`.